# Java packages: What is the difference between `oracle.AQ` and `oracle.jdbc.aq`?

Tags: java, oracle, queue, oracle-aq

What is the difference between `oracle.AQ` and `oracle.jdbc.aq` (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/aq/package-summary.html, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/overview-summary.html) ?
There seem to be 2 packages which slightly overlap.

> Java package oracle.AQ was deprecated in 10g Release 1 (10.1). Oracle recommends that you migrate existing Java AQ applications to Oracle JMS (or other Java APIs) and use Oracle JMS (or other Java APIs) to design your future Java AQ applications.

(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14257/aq_envir.htm#g1019073)

Comment: Just curious, why does it matter what a long-deprecated package (you can [see the 9i docs for it here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96609/arj_aq.htm)) did? Are you still using it and are trying to figure out how to migrate away from it perhaps?

Comment: No, documentation on Java + Oracle AQ is hard to find IMHO. I just found out that most of the examples / tutorials are based on the older `oracle.AQ`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fundamental difference between the two packages: oracle.AQ is just a Java wrapper above PLSQL AQ procedures whereas the AQ APIs offered through the JDBC thin driver ([OracleConnection.enqueue](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#enqueue_java_lang_String__oracle_jdbc_aq_AQEnqueueOptions__oracle_jdbc_aq_AQMessage_), [OracleConnection.dequeue](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#dequeue_java_lang_String__oracle_jdbc_aq_AQDequeueOptions__byte___)) implement the AQ native protocol. As a consequence the oracle.jdbc.aq APIs are going to be much faster. Oracle JMS uses the oracle.jdbc.aq APIs under the covers.